# Crear un formulario hijo limitado en C#?

Tags: c#

Me gustaria saber como es la manera correcta de crear un formulario padre y un hijo

He creado un formulario común y le he cambiado la propiedad `IsMdiContainer = True` para habilitar el contenedor y el codigo que le he puesto a mi formulario principal para abrir el formulario hijo es este:

`Opciones_Docente frmdocente = new Opciones_Docente(); frmdocente.MdiParent = this; frmdocente.Show();`

sabemos que cuando activamos la propiedad IsMdiContainer = True se pone de color gris la parte que no esta ocupada del fornulario principal y el formulario hijo abrira dentro de esa parte limitada por la propiedad `IsMdiContainer`

Pero lo que necesito es que el formulario hijo solo abarque el tamaño que le ha dado el `IsMdiContainer`, resulta que cuando el formulario hijo lo maximizo abarca todo el formulario principal y se posiciona por encima del formulario padre

En la primera imagen esta es el formulario padre con la ventana hija abierta

En la segunda imagen esta el formulario padre con la ventana hija abierta pero en esta ocación la ventana hija esta maximizada y se posiciona por encima del padre y necesito que se limite al `IsMdiContainer`

[image: Este es el formulario padre con la ventana hija abierta]

[image: pero cuando maximizo el formulario hijo se posiciona por encima del padre y necesito que se limite al IsMdiContainer]

Comment: debe ser que cambiaste alguna propiedad ya sea en el padre o en el hijo, ya que asi como lo comentas no deberias de tener problema, revisa las propiedades de ambos, cuando cambias las propiedades estas cambian el tamaño de letra, verificalos